# I want to make a stepper component

Tags: javascript, html, css, wizard, stepper

I want to hide `prev btn` and the other words

But I want to show them and `prev` btn one by one when I press `next` button and display `finish` btn i am on the latest word.

The buttons, `prev`, `next` and `finish` do the things which are not the same when I have `finish` button I want to post the words.

I tried many time but not worked. Here is my code that I've tried:

```js
function nextBtn() {
                var itemOne = document.getElementById("step-1");
                var itemTwo = document.getElementById("step-2");
                var itemThree = document.getElementById("step-3");
                var itemFour = document.getElementById("step-4");
                var prevBtn = document.getElementById("prevBtn");
                var nextBtn = document.getElementById("nextBtn");

                if (itemOne.style.display == "block" && itemTwo.style.display == "none" && prevBtn.style.display == "none") {  
                    itemOne.style.display = "none";
                    itemTwo.style.display = "block";
                    prevBtn.style.display = "block";
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Xatolik ishlamayapti');
                }
            }
```

```css
#step-1 {
    display: block;
}
#step-2 {
    display: none;
}
#step-3 {
    display: none;
}
#step-4 {
    display: none;
}
#prevBtn {
    display: none;
}
#nextBtn {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
        <div class="step-container">
            <div id="step-1">Hello</div>
            <div id="step-2">Hi</div>
            <div id="step-3">Salom</div>
            <div id="step-4">Molas</div>
            <button id="prevBtn" @click="prevBtn()">back</button>
            <button id="nextBtn" @click="nextBtn()">next</button>
        </div>
```

What's wrong at above link.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your approach is that `itemOne.style.display == "block"` will not evaluate to `true` because it doesn't consider that the node has some css set externally.

It would make more sense to use html classes for your step divs so that you can select them all at once with [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

The logic would be easier to manage if you use a variable to track which number step is the current step.

Then you can just increase and decrease the variable each time you click on either the previous or next buttons.

```js
const allSteps = document.querySelectorAll('.step')
const totalSteps = allSteps.length
const prevButton = document.querySelector('#prevBtn')
const nextButton = document.querySelector('#nextBtn')
const finishButton = document.querySelector('#finishBtn')

// Hide everything except for #step-1
document
  .querySelectorAll(".step:not(#step-1)")
  .forEach(step => (step.style.display = "none"))

// Hide the prev button
prevButton.style.display = 'none'

// Hide the finish button
finishButton.style.display = 'none'

let currentStep = 1

function nextBtn() {
  currentStep++;
  refreshDisplay()
}

function prevBtn() {
  currentStep--;
  refreshDisplay()
}

function refreshDisplay() {
  // hide every step
  allSteps.forEach(step => (step.style.display = "none"))

  // show only the currentStep
  document.querySelector(`#step-${currentStep}`).style.display = 'block'

  // hide or show the prevButton
  if (currentStep === 1) {
    prevButton.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    prevButton.style.display = 'inline-block'
  }

  // hide or show nextButton & finish button
  if (currentStep === totalSteps) {
    nextButton.style.display = 'none'
    finishButton.style.display = 'inline-block'
  } else {
    nextButton.style.display = 'inline-block'
    finishButton.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

function finish() {
  console.log('you are finished')
}
```

```html
<div class="step-container">
  <div class="step" id="step-1">Hello</div>
  <div class="step" id="step-2">Hi</div>
  <div class="step" id="step-3">Salom</div>
  <div class="step" id="step-4">Molas</div>
  <button id="prevBtn" onclick="prevBtn()">back</button>
  <button id="nextBtn" onclick="nextBtn()">next</button>
  <button id="finishBtn" onclick="finish()">finish</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var activeButton = 0;

function next() {
  document.getElementById(activeButton).classList.remove('active');
  activeButton++;
  document.getElementById(activeButton).classList.add('active');
}

function previous() {
  document.getElementById(activeButton).classList.remove('active');
  activeButton--;
  document.getElementById(activeButton).classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.step {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button id="0" class="active step">First</button>
<button id="1" class="step">Second</button>
<button id="2" class="step">Third</button>
<button id="3" class="step">Fourth</button>
<button id="4" class="step">Fifth</button>
<button id="5" class="step">Sixth</button>
<button id="6" class="step">Seventh</button>
<hr>
<button id="next" onclick="next()">Next</button>
<button id="next" onclick="previous()">Previous</button>
```

Comment: Obviously previous will work only if there was atleast one next. I skipped validations. And thanks for the code split. I couldnt figure how to do that. Newbie here :)

Comment: Hm, what about VueJS code. Can I make something like this in VueJS, too?
True, I gave this question about JavaScript. But I thought Vue And JavaScript are the same. But I just know that I was wrong. Thank you.